# PHP Error - Notice: Array to string conversion on imploding an array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to write a function that would take the `$s` parameter and split it into letters thus creating an array of the letters of `$s`.

`$n` is the letter counter, so it would loop up to 10 letters and return `EricEricEr`.

**The first issue:** I understand I'm creating an array inside an array, and since I would like to receive the string of the inner array, I would need to implode it twice.

**The Second issue:** I'm unable to print the 10 first letters, only the word 10 times (i.e. EricEricEricEric...10 times).

**Expected Result:** I would like the `for` loop `i` to go over the letters, and when reaching `$n` and print all the letters with no glue, just consecutively, receiving the result of this specific example function params as: `EricEricEr`.

```
function letterCounter($s, $n){
    for ($i = 0; $i<=$n; $i++){
        $split [] = str_split($s);
    }
    $imploded = implode($split);
    return $imploded;
}
$result = letterCounter('Eric', 10);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: i didn't get any error in your code:- https://eval.in/643264

Comment: And you -1 the question? How about reading the whole question?

Comment: nope i din't did that. i just checked your code.

Comment: There is no error in the code, read the question please.

Comment: Read your own question title :/

Comment: @clusterBuddy what is expected with this input? put that in the form of array or something, not in words.

Comment: I re-edit the code for the error.

Comment: https://eval.in/643279  ? is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do but you can improve the code

```
function letterCounter($s, $n)
{
    $split = str_split($s); //array of splitted $s into letters
    $count=0;
    $str = "";
    while($count<$n){

        foreach($split as $char){
            if($count>=$n)
                break;
            $str.= $char;
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $str;
}

$result = letterCounter('Eric', 10);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Excellent Answer, thanks. Please upvote my question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you right here, but PHP got everything you need:

```
$string = "Eric";
str_pad($string, 10, $string);
```

> "EricEricEr"